# How to hide particular Schemas/models that are shown in end of swagger documentation page in NestJS?

Tags: nestjs, dto, nestjs-swagger

I want to hide some schemas from the Swagger documentation page in **NestJS**. I have already checked the [issue](https://github.com/nestjs/swagger/issues/722) but it is for hiding all the schemas.
I want to show only few schemas in the documentation page. I have tried renaming the `DTO` from file name and Class names but the schema is not hiding.